# Port C# AES 256 CBC encryption to PHP using openssl

Tags: c#, php, encryption, aes, port

I'm trying to port an encryption/decryption algorithm (AES 256 CBC) from C# to PHP (using openssl), and I can't get it to yield the same results.

In C# the code is as follows:
(https://dotnetfiddle.net/GNKR7r)

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;
                    
public class Program
{
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        string original = "some-text";
        string key = "1234567890123456";
        
        string encrypted = Program.Aes256Encrypt(original, key);
        string decrypted = Program.Aes256Decrypt(encrypted, key);
        
        Console.WriteLine("original: " + original);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("encrypted: " + encrypted);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("decrypted: " + decrypted);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public static string Aes256Encrypt(string input, string password)
    {
        using (var aes = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            aes.KeySize = 256;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aes.IV = new byte[16] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F };

            if (password.Length > 16)
                password = password.Substring(0, 16);

            byte[] pwd = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
            aes.Key = pwd;

            byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(bytesToBeEncrypted, 0, bytesToBeEncrypted.Length);
                }
                var msArray = ms.ToArray();
                return Convert.ToBase64String(msArray);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static string Aes256Decrypt(string input, string password)
    {
        using (var aes = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            aes.KeySize = 256;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aes.IV = new byte[16] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F };

            if (password.Length > 16)
                password = password.Substring(0, 16);

            byte[] pwd = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
            aes.Key = pwd;

            byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(input);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(bytesToBeDecrypted, 0, bytesToBeDecrypted.Length);
                }
                var msArray = ms.ToArray();
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msArray, 0, msArray.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the result:

```
original: some-text

encrypted: UBhArY1q0fuYxRlS0h0dYQ==

decrypted: some-text
```

In PHP I have tried several combinations of configs, and I think this one should work but it doesn't: (You can use this to fiddle with the PHP: https://wtools.io/php-sandbox)

```php
<?php

const CIPHER = 'aes-256-cbc';

$original = "some-text";

$key = '1234567890123456';

$iv = '0123456789abcdef';


$encrypted = aes256Encrypt($original, $key, $iv);
echo openssl_error_string();
$decrypted = aes256Decrypt($encrypted, $key, $iv);
echo openssl_error_string();

echo "\n";
echo "original: " . $original . "\n";
echo "\n";
echo "encrypted: " . $encrypted . "\n";
echo "\n";
echo "decrypted: " . $decrypted . "\n";
echo "\n";

function aes256Encrypt(string $input, string $password, string $iv): string
{
    return base64_encode(openssl_encrypt(mb_convert_encoding($input, 'UTF-8'), CIPHER, mb_convert_encoding($password, 'UTF-8'), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
}

function aes256Decrypt(string $input, string $password, string $iv): string
{
    return openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($input), CIPHER, mb_convert_encoding($password, 'UTF-8'), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
}
```

With the result:

```
original: some-text

encrypted: Lbz5pDs2/ZhNY7WF8gKtFw== 

decrypted: some-text
```

What I need is for the PHP script to yield the same encryption result as the C# one.

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that you need the encrypted data string to be the same whether or not it was encrypted in PHP or C#?

Comment: In the PHP code the IV differ (correct: `$iv = hex2bin('000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f')`) and also the algorithm (correct: `const CIPHER = 'aes-128-cbc'`). BTW, a static IV is insecure.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Yes, exactly.

Comment: It is likely that the point made by @Topaco could be the issue. A different IV will yield a different result and your PHP IV is hardcoded as a different string. If you set the IV the same in both does the result change to your liking?

Comment: @Topaco Changing the IV alone as you mentioned didn't work. I think the cipher should be AES 256. In C# they need to specify the block size 128 which is the AES spec (special case of Rijndael), and used by default by PHP.
The static IV is static only until I finally get it to work :)

And tkx btw.

Comment: If you apply the described changes, the PHP code will return the same ciphertext as the PHP code, see online here: https://paiza.io/projects/teKvfc6pk6ozGATmr4ke6Q

Comment: @Topaco YOU R THA MAN!

Feel free to make it your answer and I will set it as accepted.